# get two tasks to apply plugin gradle

Tags: gradle, plugins

Is there a way to have two tasks in gradle and have both return the proper values setting parameters within the plugins

I have:

**Build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'gradle.plugin'

task FirstTask(type: com.nav.Coding){
  param.dictFile = file ("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/customized_struct.xml")
  param.outputDirectory = file("${buildDir}/generated/"
}

task SecondTask(type: com.nav.Coding){
  param.dictFile = file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/customized_struct_two.xml")
  param.outputDirectory = file("${buildDir}/generated/"
}
```

For some reason my output is only taking the second `dictFile` and not the first when setting the parameters to the JVM and processing the custom  plugin.

**Command Output**

> $ gradle -q FirstTask SecondTask

```
:com:nav:Coding:FirstTask
Processing C:\dev\src\main\resources\customized_struct_two.xml
This is my output dictFile C:\dev\src\main\resources\customized_struct_two.xml
This is my output outputDirectory C:\dev\build\generated

:com:nav:Coding:SecondTask
Processing C:\dev\src\main\resources\customized_struct_two.xml
This is my output dictFile C:\dev\src\main\resources\customized_struct_two.xml
This is my output outputDirectiory C:\dev\build\generated

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 12.79 secs
```

Comment: What is `param`?  Some global config object?

Comment: It is the plugin name created in my groovy class `project.getExtensions().create("param",Coding.ParamPluginExtension.class)`

Comment: Both tasks are outputting to `${buildDir}/generated` so this could be causing issues. Either output to separate directories per task or ensure that the `TaskOutputs` for `com.nav.Coding` are granular to the exact file (and not the directory)

Comment: @LanceJava My Plugin utilizes the `dictFile` xml and generates code based on the values within the xml. I would like to output the generated files within the same directory...When I comment out one of the Tasks it generates classes within `${buildDir}/generated` and vice-versa (other commented out) I feel my issue is the second task is taking priority and setting the parameters on the plugin vs first task completing and then second using the second dictionary file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I beleive you are falling for the common mistake of putting logic in the `configuration` phase instead of the `execution` phase. I beleive you want to:

```
task FirstTask(type: com.nav.Coding){
    doFirst {
        param.dictFile = file ("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/customized_struct.xml")
        param.outputDirectory = file("${buildDir}/generated/"
    }
}

task SecondTask(type: com.nav.Coding){
    doFirst {
        param.dictFile = file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/customized_struct_two.xml")
        param.outputDirectory = file("${buildDir}/generated/"
    }
}
```

This feels wierd to me

1. Where does `param` come from?
2. Why aren't `dictFile` and `outputDirectory` properties on the `com.nav.Coding` task?

Comment: This worked! 

But I would like to know why adding doFirst gave me the desired result...

Comment: Gradle has a `configuration` phase and an `execution` phase. You had the logic in the `configuration` phase which runs before any tasks are executed. `doFirst` and `doLast` closures are executed in the `execution` phase... when the task is actually running. Try adding `println` statements alongside your configuration and you'll see what I mean

Comment: Awesome!...Thanks for the reply and clarification!

Comment: Sorry...`param` comes from a plugin name that I created in a groovy class file...I'm using it to qualify a property that I'm setting for a quickfixJ code generator...

`dictFile and `outputDirectory` ARE in my properties but I'm overriding them to create classes based on properties I would like to give based on runtime

Comment: Clear as mud. You should add these properties to the task itself. Then you could initialize in the configuration phase because each task instance has its own values. What you're doing is hacky

Comment: But the properties are variable...are you suggesting adding these properties in my groovy code?

Comment: I'm suggesting to add `dictFile` and `outputDirectory` properties to the `com.nav.Coding`task so each instance has its own copy rather than multiple tasks sharing globals which you change in `doFirst`